# Trigger to update the owner of child record to the owner of parent record (look up relationship)

Tags: apex, trigger, field-update

I have a custom object called "Recurring Storage Revenue". This object is populated via integration so the owner of the revenue records is the system user. I need to build a trigger so that the owner of the revenue records is updated to the owner of the parent record (the standard Account object) whenever the revenue record is created or updated. I am getting some errors to the trigger I wrote - any thoughts? Also would appreciate a test class if possible?

```
trigger UpdateOwnerID on Recurring_Storage_Revenue__c (before insert, before update) {

Map<Id,Id> accIdToNewOwnerId = new Map<Id,Id>();
for(Recurring_Storage_Revenue__c rsr : [Select 
                        Id, 
                        OwnerId, 
                        Account.OwnerId 
                    From 
                        Recurring_Storage_Revenue__c 
                    Where 
                        Id in :trigger.NewMap.keySet() 
                    AND 
                        OwnerId != Account.OwnerId])
{
    // if the opp owner deviates from the relatedrecord owner, add to the map
    accIdToNewOwnerId.put(rsr.Id,rsr.Account.OwnerId);
}

// now go through the records in the trigger and update where applicable
for(Recurring_Storage_Revenue__c rsr : trigger.new)
{
    if(accIdToNewOwnerId.containsKey(rsr.Id)){
        rsr.OwnerId = accIdToNewOwnerId.get(rsr.Id);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: what is the error message you are getting?

Comment: Looks like a before trigger which is fine but you won't have an Id in Trigger.new how exactly are you pulling the records?

Comment: was wondering if I could get help with that!

Comment: Make the context after insert/update!

Comment: I suggest you to check @Ishwar's answer and go with process builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]Check the snapshot where I managed to update owner of the opportunity to its Account's owner.

You can check this process.

[Reference](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000220346&language=en_UShttp://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000220346&language=en_US)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, changed the event to after insert

```
trigger UpdateOwnerID on Recurring_Storage_Revenue__c (after insert) {

List<Recurring_Storage_Revenue__c> updateList = new List<Recurring_Storage_Revenue__c>();
Map<Id,Id> accIdToNewOwnerId = new Map<Id,Id>();
for(Recurring_Storage_Revenue__c rsr : [Select 
                        Id, 
                        OwnerId, 
                        Account.OwnerId 
                    From 
                        Recurring_Storage_Revenue__c 
                    Where 
                        Id in :trigger.NewMap.keySet() 
                    AND 
                        OwnerId != :Account.OwnerId])
{
    // if the opp owner deviates from the relatedrecord owner, add to the map
    accIdToNewOwnerId.put(rsr.Id,rsr.Account.OwnerId);
}

// now go through the records in the trigger and update where applicable
for(Recurring_Storage_Revenue__c rsr : trigger.new)
{
    if(accIdToNewOwnerId.containsKey(rsr.Id)){
        rsr.OwnerId = accIdToNewOwnerId.get(rsr.Id);
        updateList.add(rsr);
    }
}
update updateList;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but am getting following error: Error: Compile Error: expecting a colon, found 'Account.OwnerId' at line 14 column 35

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: can you try now, i updated my answer

Comment: this is the next error: Error: Compile Error: Didn't understand relationship 'Account' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. at line 5 column 40

Comment: what is the childrelationship name on field relation to account?

Comment: the API name is just Account__c

Comment: when you open the field, you can find a "Child Relationship Name"